# Batch unrar but file has to stay in folder

Tags: batch-file, extract, unrar

So I have a large unrar job. Here is the layout of the directory:

```
MAIN DIR
    SUBFOLDER
        file1.rar
        file1.r00
        file1.r01
```

The end result is:

```
MAIN DIR
    SUBFOLDER
        extracted.file
```

To perfect this, it would also delete the `.rar` files and rename the `extracted.file` to the name of the subfolder, that would be awesome if possible.

Comment: I assume your question is how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
del *.r*
ren extracted.file %~dp0.*
```

Maybe best to prompt to delete the `*.r*` files (`del *.r* /p`) before doing it automatically, just to make sure there are no others that you want to keep (as long as it only contains rar files then it should be fine).